Is it Appropriate to Request a Seminar Invitation from a University Department as a research Student?
As a PhD student traveling to a city with a university that has a department in your field of research, is it appropriate or ethical to reach out to the department to inquire about the possibility of giving a research talk during your visit?

I hope you are not after getting your travel costs covered. Probably everybody is assuming so, too. Just to make it explicit.

I would expect these communications to go through a professor at the institution who is formally or informally "sponsoring" your visit.
If you're just in the city for other things, I suppose you could reach out to someone at the institution whose interests align with yours and discuss meeting and possibly presenting your work, but I think I would start with just proposing to meet and work out whether presenting makes sense from there.

Your question title and body paragraphs have slightly different questions.

Is it Appropriate to Request a Seminar Invitation from a University Department as a research Student?

No. Requesting a seminar or requesting anything else would be rude.

As a PhD student traveling to a city with a university that has a department in your field of research, is it appropriate or ethical to reach out to the department to inquire about the possibility of giving a research talk during your visit?

Bryan's answer covers this situation nicely.
I would just add that dropping an email to someone with overlapping interests and saying you are in town and would like to chat seems reasonable.
They may not respond simply because they are busy or your email slips through the cracks or they may invite you to an informally meet with people in their program.
Or, they might even invite you to give a seminar or guest lecture.
A guest lecture might be possible if you are reaching out to a primary teaching university and your research overlaps with a class.
A lot of your response or lack of response will be chance.

In my field (physics) this is completely reasonable, as there is usually a culture of weekly seminars in each subfield. Already as a postdoc I have done this a bunch of times, usually when I am invited some place to give a talk and there are other universities I'd like to visit in nearby cities. But also sometimes when I'm visiting some place for vacation I think it's fun to meet the local physicists.
It works better if you contact them further in advance so there is a higher chance of a free slot in their schedule. It works better if you have some pre-existing contact in the department, even if that's a grad student you know or a professor who's a friend of your adviser. But even if not, you can email a postdoc or professor in your area of research and ask about it.
Of course it also works better if you've been writing papers that people have found interesting. If they really want to hear what you have to say, you might be invited to stay for a couple days to chat with everyone and to give a talk and taken to dinner. And they might offer to pay for your hotel and train tickets and local expenses. This is more likely later in your career though.

It all depends on field and country. In some places and fields, seminars are prestigious and asking to be invited to such a seminar, especially as a student, comes across as presumptuous. This could be a career limiting event. In others, seminars are held in order to exchange ideas in research groups and are informal. And in many places, both forms of seminars exist. Sometimes, departments like to invite speakers to a colloquy in order to expose their students to a variety of ideas, and you coming by would help them fill up their schedule.
If you seek contact:

Have it come from your advisor, who is also supposed to guide you in scientific etiquette
Ask them for a chance to meet them and see what they propose. This can result in a chatting with an important person or it can result in giving a seminar to the graduate students, etc. But it will be their decision and you cannot do anything wrong.


Certainly a faux pas, but I am surprised that this could anywhere be a "career-limiting event"!

Known to not know academic customs or having the reputation to think to highly of oneself are career-limiting.
